# Microsoft exchange server data breach relevance to IND-CPA, IND-CCA1, IND-CCA2

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

I was studying about the Microsoft exchange server data breach attack of 2021 as part of assignment case study. One of the tasks of the assignment it to find its relevance with IND-CPA, IND-CCA1, IND-CCA2 standards.

From my understanding the attack is seemed to be caused due to some logical bugs in the code base of certain versions of exchange server and attacker exploiting it with intelligently crafted HTTP request. While this standards talk about the strength of any encryption scheme.

Is there any possible link between the attack and standards that I am missing, is there any relevance between them at all?

Comment: IND-CPA (or IND-CCA1, IND-CCA2) is not a _standard_ (noun). It's a _security property_ for an encryption scheme, and has a standard (adjective) definition. The [info on Wikipedia about the data breach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Microsoft_Exchange_Server_data_breach) is low on detail, do you have a better source?

Comment: @fgrieu please refer this blog. https://devco.re/blog/2021/08/06/a-new-attack-surface-on-MS-exchange-part-1-ProxyLogon/

Comment: Part 2 links the relevant CVE: https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-31196

Comment: There was a padding oracle attack. We don't provide direct answers to homework, but knowing the phrase "padding oracle" should be enough to figure out which IND- property/properties got violated.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus What do you exactly mean by "There was a padding oracle attack" ? Also I am not looking for direct answer, just a hint or reference to get unblocked.

Comment: padding oracle attack is a standard phrase/technique, so that's a hint for what to read more about. In particular, you should examine whether an adversary can execute a padding oracle attack in the INDCPA, INDCCA1, or INDCCA2 attack models. These are linearly ordered, in the sense that if an adversary can execute the attack in the INDCPA model they can execute it in the INDCCA1 model (and similarly for INDCCA1 and INDCCA2). What is the minimal model they can execute the attack in though?